# How to apply Euler's Formula in topology to this problem?

Tags: general-topology, problem-solving

> Prove that it is impossible to make a football out of exactly 9 squares
>   and $m$ octagons, where $m \ge 4$. (In this context, a “football” is a convex
>   polyhedron in which at least 3 edges meet at each vertex.)

I think the number of faces, $F$, is $9+m$, but I don't know how to count the number of edges $E$, and the number of vertices, $V$.

How shall I count them? Is there a clever way of thinking?

Comment: Tip: how many edges are there if you count all polygons separately? And how many faces is each edge shared by?

Comment: @Ezueneok Is there a way to count the number of vertices? Does the number of vertices depend on the way the squares and octagons are put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Euler's formula for convex polyhedrons is
$$v-e+f=2$$
from the question we have
$$f = 9+m,\quad e = 9\cdot 2 +m\cdot 4,\quad e \ge \frac{3}{2}v$$
For the inequality, for each vertex there are at least 3 edges, but an edge is shared between 2 vertices. Similar for the second equality 2 faces share one edge.

Now we plug everything together.

$$
v-e+f = 2
\:\Longleftrightarrow\:
v - 18 - 4m + 9+m = 2
\:\Longleftrightarrow\:
v = 11 + 3m
$$

Hence we have
$$
11 + 3m = v \le \frac{2}{3} e = \frac{2}{3} 18 + \frac{2}{3} 4m
\:\Longrightarrow\:
\frac{1}{3}m \le 1
\:\Longleftrightarrow\:
m \le 3.
$$
which is not allowed because of the given constraint $m \ge 4$.$\Box$

Comment: How did you arrive at $e = 9 \times 2 + m \times 4$?

Comment: Read the questions I commented. andre has already answered one of these questions for you: each edge is shared by two faces. Calculating the number of edges of $9$ squares and $m$ octagons (unconnected!) is easy. So if you connect all these polygons into a football, you force every two edges to become one shared edge... In fact, andre was nice enough to leave the expression for $e$ suggestive: you recognise the $9$ and the $m$, so where do the $2$ and $4$ come from?

Comment: what?? why was I down-voted?

Comment: @andre Please do not delete this answer, I need it! This answer is excellent! Up-voted, you're welcome.